# Parsing out body and tables from emails

Tags: python, html, email, parsing

I currently am getting the body/content of the emails in Python using the following:

```
import email
message = email.message_from_file(open(file))
messages = [part.get_payload() for part in message.walk() if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain']
```

This seems to work well in most cases, but I noticed that sometimes there are html tables that don't get picked up. It starts with

```
<html>
<style type='text/css">
```

Would it just be to add or `part.get_content_tye() == 'text/css'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to guess, I would guess that you need to add 'text/html'.

However, you should be able to figure out what content-type is in the email by examining the content of that variable.

```
import email
message = email.message_from_file(open(file))


# Remove the content-type filter completely
messages = [(part.get_payload(), part.get_content_type()) for part in message.walk()]


# print the whole thing out so that you can see what content-types are in there.
print(message)
```

This will help you see what content types are in there and you can then filter the ones that you need.

Comment: Thank you. It was 'text/html'. I was able to find it in the metadata.